# Rigging creature

Tags: rigging, armature, audio

I have asked this question before, but I'm still struggling with uploading my blender file. Could the file size be responsible for that? I followed the instructions I got from you, but I still can't upload my file.

However, I rigged again, saved and closed. When I opened the file again, rigs and objects separated too far or just expanded strangely as I showed already.
And third, my audio file doesn't work even I followed to import my audio file step by step.

1. Blend File Uploading Error
2. Rigs separated apart/elongated
3. Audio doesn't sound

[image: This is my creature and rigs separated when I reopened my blender file. I feel something wrong from selecting arms separately too, which I followed through Youtube video.]

Please help me, guys. My project is due next week and I must render my animations this weekend. Thanks for everyone's kind helps and replies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rigging problems after reopening files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137344/rigging-problems-after-reopening-files)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question twice, if you have details info edit and update your original question and follow the advice given in the comments section, instead of making a new post.

Comment: I just deleted.